# Date Formats list for string parse intl package dart

Tags: date, flutter, dart, date-format

im using intl package in flutter to parse the date string, my date string is read from ocr so its format is different, I need to collect maximum date formats to avoid date parse issues
Currently I have only collected two

```
  static List<String> dateFormats = ['dd MMM y HH:mm', 'dd MMM y HH:mm:ss'];
```

Suggest me some date formats to add more date formats to my date Formats list string

Answer (score 0):

You can find all possible formats for every parts of date string
and combine them to have all date format strings:

Year:

```
//'yyyy' formatDate(DateTime(1989), [yyyy]); => 1989

//'yy' formatDate(DateTime(1989), [yy]); => 89
```

Month:

```
//'mm' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 11), [mm]); => 11

//'m' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 5), [m]); => 5

//'MM' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 2), [MM]); => february

//'M' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 2), [M]); => feb
```

Day:

```
//'dd' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 2, 5), [dd]); => 05

//'d' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 2, 5), [d]); => 5

//'DD' formatDate(DateTime(2018, 1, 14), [DD]); => sunday

//'D' formatDate(DateTime(2018, 1, 14), [D]); => sun
```

Hour:

```
//'hh'  formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 15), [hh]); => 03

//'h'     formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 15), [h]); => 3

//'HH' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 15), [HH]); => 15

//'H' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 5), [H]); => 5
```

Minute:

```
//'nn' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 15, 4), [nn]); => 04

//'n' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 15, 4), [n]); => 4
```

Seconds:

```
//'ss' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 15, 40, 5), [ss]); => 05

//'s' formatDate(DateTime(1989, 02, 1, 15, 40, 5), [s]); => 5
```

[Here](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) is other possible formats.